# modify connect.static responses

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I want the functionality of `connect.static`, but I want to inject code into any HTML and JavaScript files that are served.

1. Can I hook into `connect.static` to modify the data it serves?
2. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect.static isn't the right choice for this. The static middleware is specifically for serving static content directly from disk.

Look at connect-assetmanager (https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager), it has a serveModify hook that should do what you're needing.

Comment: I think that library will work, but the content seems to be gzipped by the time it gets to my `serveModify` handler. I've had no luck disabling that behavior. Any tips?

Comment: Interesting point. At this time, I don't believe there is way to get it. The gzipping was added back in January, I think, create an issue on github about the order of the gzipping and someone will probably fix it.